# Python Looping To Produce Output On Separate Lines

Tags: python

I am new to programming and was trying to create a program in python that creates a staircase with size based on the user input. The program should appear as shown below:

[image: Favorable Output]

This is the code I have so far;

```
steps = int(input('How many steps? '))
print('__')
for i in range(steps):
  n = steps+i
  print(' '*(n-2) + '|_')
print('_'*n + '|')
```

This is what my output is;

[image: My Output]

Note - The horizontal lines are underscores '_' and the vertical lines are the pipe character '|'.

Answer (score 1):

To get the correct amount of steps, you have to change the for loop to:

```
for i in range(steps-1):
```

This is because you want to print the `|_`'s one less time than there are steps; your "top" step `__` already counts as one step.

The whole thing (changed some other things to make the formatting better):

```
steps = int(input('How many steps? '))
print('__')
for i in range(steps-1):
    print(' '*(2+2*i) + '|_')
print('_'*2*steps + '|')
```

Output:

[image: output]

Answer (score 0):

It is simpler to consider that `n` is the current step and given the step size (2) then you just need `2n` for your placement:

```
steps = 5
print('__')
for n in range(1, steps):
    print(' '*n*2 + '|_')
print('_'*steps*2 + '|')
```

Output:

```
__
  |_
    |_
      |_
        |_
__________|
```

You can abstract this to take any step size, e.g.:

```
steps = 5
size = 4
print('_'*size)
for n in range(1, steps):
    print(' '*n*size + '|' + '_'*(size-1))
print('_'*steps*size + '|')
```

Output:

```
____
    |___
        |___
            |___
                |___
____________________|
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def stairs(steps):
    print("__")
    length = 1
    for i in range(steps):
        length += 1
        print("%s|_" % (" "*(length+i)),)
    print("%s|" % ("_"*(length+steps+1)),)

stairs(4)
```

Output:

```
__
  |_
    |_
      |_
        |_
__________|
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via `while`. 
    `counter = 0
     while counter < steps:
        Create_stairs()
        increase counter`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your exact question is. The patter of steps is:

- Step 1 -> 4 blanks
- Step 2 -> 6 blanks
- Step 3 -> 8 blanks
- Step n -> 2 + (2 * n) blanks

  steps = int(input('How many steps? '))

Comment: Note: Step 1 is only 2 blanks

Comment: Huh, you are right, started counting from 0 again ;-)